# Client validation did not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

In my project used ASP.NET MVC 5. I've used `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` for validation.
I expect when I don't enter value for a  mandatory field,be prevent to continue my action.
But this expectation does't satisfy.
How can I solve this problem?

```
@model Jahan.Blog.ViewModel.ArticleViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Article</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

    @*There are some codes*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
    </div>

    @*There are some codes*@

   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
}
```

***ViewModel:***

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(ArticleViewModelBinder))]
public class ArticleViewModel : IArticleViewModel
{
    public ArticleViewModel()
    {

    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

***Controller:***

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Prefix = "")]ArticleViewModel articleViewModel, List<int> availableTags)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // There are some codes.
        }
        return View(articleViewModel);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js are loaded?

Comment: I forgot to add  jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js. I added and worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Fiskeboss's comment, `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` library added.Then it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

open your **web.config** and find `ClientValidationEnabled` in `appSettings` and check if it's set as true :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: I got my answer by @fiskeboss.